# Executing DateTime.Parse on a tuple in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, tuples, specflow

Is there a way to execute `DateTime.Parse` on a tuple in C#.

I am using Specflow and part of the tests I am executing involve testing a list of `DateTime` tuples (e.g. `List<(DateTime, DateTime)>`). In this step I am taking in a string, parsing it into a list of strings, where each string represents a `DateTime` pair separated by `=`.

The plan was to create a tuple store the value by splitting the string, creating a string tuple, then parsing that tuple using `DateTime.Parse`.

This doesn't work, giving me a CS1503 error (*Argument n: cannot convert from 'type x' to 'type y'*), and I cannot find any other information online about using `DateTime.Parse` on tuples. Is there another way of changing these values into `DateTime`?

Below is an extract of my code for reference:

```cs
public class TimeModeServiceStepDefinitions
{
    List<(DateTime, DateTime)> expectedResult = new List<(DateTime, DateTime)>();

    [Given(@"I have the following list of expected results: '([^']*)'")]
    public void GivenIHaveTheFollowingListOfExpectedResults(string p0)
    {
        List<string> tuples = p0.Split('|').ToList();
        foreach (var tuple in tuples)
        {
            var timeTuple = (first: "first", second: "second");
            timeTuple = tuple.Split('=') switch { var a => (a[0], a[1]) };
            expectedResult.Add(DateTime.Parse(timeTuple));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it takes in a string to parse as the parameter. If you can write this what is preventing you from passing `DateTime.Parse` a string arguments from your `timeTuple` instance and then assigning the results to a `(DateTime, DateTime)` tuple instance?

Comment: why not just parse each `DateTime` individually and do `expectedResult.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(DateTime.Parse(timeTuple.Item1), DateTime.Parse(timeTuple.Item2)));`

Comment: It is not clear what input your step definition is receiving, so it is difficult to recommend a fix. Can you [edit] your question to include the step from the feature file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime.Parse` accepts a string supposed to contain one date/time. So, we can simply write:

```cs
string[] a = tupleString.Split('=');
var timeTuple = (first: DateTime.Parse(a[0]), second: DateTime.Parse(a[1]));
```

where `timeTuple` is of type `(DateTime first, DateTime second)`.

`var timeTuple = (first: "first", second: "second");` is a strange way of declaring a tuple variable. C# does not only have a tuple syntax for tuple values but also for tuple types:

```cs
(DateTime first, DateTime second) namedTuple;
(DateTime, DateTime) unnamedTuple; // With elements named Item1, Item2
```

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, you'd just map `DateTime.Parse` over a tuple, but I don't think there is a way to do so as part of standard library. You can easily write an extension that would help you write such code (Select is essentially the name chosen for map operation in LINQ):

```
static class TupleExtensions
{
    public static (TResult,TResult) Select<T,TResult>(
        this (T,T) v, Func<T,TResult> f)
          => (f(v.Item1), f(v.Item2));
}
```

And then you can write:

```
    string p0 = "2022-11-11=2022-12-12";
    List<string> tuples = p0.Split('|').ToList();
    var expectedResult = 
         tuples.Select(tuple => tuple.Split('=') switch { var a => (a[0], a[1]) })
         .Select(x => x.Select(DateTime.Parse))
         .ToList();
```

Comment: You probably should fix up your automated ChatGPT posting script...